# Using ActiveDirectory.Platform in .net core app

Tags: azure-active-directory, .net-core

I am writing a console app in .net core which is using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory for user authentication.

The nuget package contains two files in lib\netcore45 folder:

- Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll
- Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform.dll

In the code I am trying to call the AcquireTokenAsync overload with the PlatformParameters object:

```
public async Task<AuthenticationResult> AcquireTokenAsync(string resource, string clientId, Uri redirectUri, IPlatformParameters parameters)
```

The implementation of IPlatformParameters is defined in assembly Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform.dll.

How should this assembly be referenced from .net core? The project.json file does not seem to allow picking a specific file from a nuget package...

Or is there another way to consume ActiveDirectory libraries in .net core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netcore45 targets UWP. Nuget should automatically pull the dlls as needed for each target type.

Comment: Damn, of course. Why would .net core be called netcore? :) The compiler actually uses dlls from netstandard1.4 folder, which does not have a definition for PromptBehavior...

Comment: Should the PromptBehavior be available in ASP.Net Core 2.0 ? How can you acquire a token inside core 2.0 ?